# Control from first VC to another VC's actions and get data back?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 4 VC's called VC, VC1, VC2 and global VC. VC1 and VC2 have one button and label. When click that button label status will be changed. Same as VC2. There is a class called Global VC. I want to import all required functions(VC1 and VC2 functions)into that Global VC.

Now control VC1 and VC2 buttons from VC accessing functions from Global VC[Not form VC1 and VC2] after that i want to get back data.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please consider adding some code examples regarding what your issue actually is. It is a bit hard to understand from what you are saying. Show how you embed this `UIViewController`'s

Answer (score 1):

To communicate data between two or more VC. You can do any of this **approach**:

1. Delegate protocol - if you have one-to-one relation.
2. Pass data in closures(view controllers class).
3. KVO
4. RXSwift (Reactive programming)